# PCI-e sata drive as boot device

Tags: hard-drive, boot, motherboard, bios, sata

I have an acer desktop pc. I have diagnosed that the motherboard sata controller is defective.

I have bought [this card](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B004BUL7Z2) in hopes that I could connect my hard drive to it.

But when I try to boot, PC says it can not find boot drive.

In the acer bios I have options to set boot device to HD, CD/DVD, removable, and network(I think).

In advanced options, I can turn off integrated sata controller (which I have done).

The PCI-e sata card is not giving me any BIOS to boot to.

Does this just mean that the acer mobo is not capable of booting to a sata PCI-e controller?

Do I need to check if the PCI-e card has to have something in its BIOS reconfigured?

Comment: It does indeed sound like your hardware does not have the capability to boot to your drive connected to that card

Comment: In the BIOS, does the drive you have connected to the daughter card show up?

Comment: Does your card initialize on bootup showing the attached drives before saying it cannot find a boot drive?  Could you move to a USB thumb drive for a boot drive as a alternative.  We use the San Disk Extreme Cruzer as they are very fast for a great price.  Its almost a guarantee that if you can boot into an OS, you would have access to the drive on the daughter card there.  Kind of a work around I know, but it would at least let you keep working on you existing hardware.